# Wowza stream engine no sound in html player

Tags: html, audio, video, video-streaming, wowza

I use the tutorial at
https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?43-How-to-set-up-live-video-recording, and by using FlashRTMPPlayer11 I can record webcam streams and also play with no problem.

But, when I copy the recorded video file(wowza_output.mp4) and give the video to a html video player as a source, there is no sound coming. Also I have same issue when I try to open the video in vlc player.

I tried transcoders also and try to convert to sound encoding to aac, but still not working.

Help please...

Answer (score 0):

The audio codec used for a Flash app's live stream recording should be Speex, so your video player should support playing back Speex audio in order to play it correctly. Transcoding to AAC should fix it, but you can't currently transcode a VOD file in Wowza. If you're using a different encoder to re-encode in AAC, like ffmpeg, the command should be:

```
ffmpeg -i wowza_output.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a libvo_aacenc wowza_output_aac.mp4
```

When you launch the Flash application, it should prompt you to allow it to use your camera/microphone. Make sure that you enable this. You can set the Flash Player Camera and Mic settings from the Flash Player Settings Manager.

You may also want to test a different browser.

Answer (score 0):

Using Wowza transcoders - and setting their transcoder to convert to AAC audio format should do the trick. Maybe you have miss-configured something.

Don't forget to enable the transcoder, and also be sure that you are looking for the **new** source file (as you will have two of them now), and not for the old source.

Also, if you are making an API call to record an stream, make sure you change the `&streamname=your_stream` to the `&streamname=your_stream_transcoded_name`